# ListPreference without PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, listpreference

How to create ListPreference when button is clicked without PreferenceActivity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListPreference` can only be used by `PreferenceActivity`. Use a `ListView` in a regular `Activity`.

Comment: I want ListPreference working like context menu not like listview

Comment: @Depdroid: That comment makes absolutely no sense.